# Ionic 3.0 - LazyLoad Image, Only the first image was display and the rest are still using the default image?

Tags: ionic3

I have to implement the lazy load in a image it is working but there is still problem, only the first image from the array is shown after the lazy-load and the rest of the image use default image instead of the image from the array. I need help on how to fix ?

Version : -
Angular version 2.0
Ionic version 3.0

```
<img [defaultImage]="userProduct.defaultImage" [lazyLoad]="userProduct?.ImageCollection[0].url" [offset]="offset">[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Could you please create a stackblitz project so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: sir without stackblitz it is possible ?